# Differences between dayjs() of two strings

Tags: typescript, dayjs

I do not know why the following test output is false:

```
const test = "2022-12-10T06:51:00Z"

    if (dayjs(test) == dayjs("2022-12-10T06:51:00Z")){
        console.log('true')
    } else {
        console.log('false')
    }
```

although this test is true

```
const test = "2022-12-10T06:51:00Z"

    if (test == "2022-12-10T06:51:00Z"){
        console.log('true')
    } else {
        console.log('false')
    }
```

Could anyone please explain why the first test is false?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because every time you call `dayjs`, it returns a new object. No matter the values that you are passing through is the same or not.

```
const obj1 = dayjs("2022-12-10T06:51:00Z");  
const obj2 = dayjs("2022-12-10T06:51:00Z");
console.log(obj1 === obj2);
```

As you can see `obj1` and `obj2` are two different objects with different references in memory. So they are not equal.

But when you compare two strings, if the values are the same, the comparison check becomes `true`.

```
const test = "2022-12-10T06:51:00Z";
console.log(test == "2022-12-10T06:51:00Z");
```

You can read more about object references and copying [here](https://javascript.info/object-copy).

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand more about referencing and copying objects.  Actually I have `const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date|null>(new Date(task.start))` , where task object was fetched from django backend, start is a datetimefield. I can see the actual date from console.log(new Date()), but invalid date from console.log(value).  Do you have any idea to fix that issue?

Comment: This is another question that you can write and give more explanation about the situation . What you have written in the comment needs more clarity.